# XSLT- how to display the first word of the paragraph as BOLD

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am unable to do this. I am using XML file, which will be converted to HTML using XSLT. 
The sample XML file would be like this...

```
<name>ABC</name>
<dob>09-Jan-1973</dob>
..
..
<info>My name is ABC. I am working with XYZ Ltd.

I have an experience of 5 years.

I have been working on Java platform since 5 years.
</info>
```

The info tag contains information which is in the form of paragraphs. I want the first word bold.
Following will be the HTML output, only for info tag..

```
<b>My</b> name is ABC. I am working with XYZ Ltd.

<b>I</b> have an...

<b>I</b> have been working....
```

Have a nice day
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This transformation** (XSLT 2.0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="info">
  <xsl:variable name="vParas" select="tokenize(.,'&#xA;')[normalize-space()]"/>

   <xsl:for-each select="$vParas">
    <xsl:variable name="vHead" select=
        "tokenize(., '[\s.?!,;:\-]+')[.][1]"/>
    <b>
      <xsl:sequence select="$vHead"/>
    </b>
    <xsl:sequence select="substring-after(., $vHead)"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="'&#xA;&#xA;'"/>
     </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided input** (massaged into a wellformed XML document):

```
<t>
    <name>ABC</name>
    <dob>09-Jan-1973</dob> .. .. 
    <info>My name is ABC.

    I am working with XYZ Ltd.

    I have an experience of 5 years.

    I have been working on Java platform since 5 years. </info>
</t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<b>My</b> name is ABC. 

<b>I</b> am working with XYZ Ltd. 

<b>I</b> have an experience of 5 years. 

<b>I</b> have been working on Java platform since 5 years.
```

And this displays in the browser as expected:

---

**My** name is ABC.

**I** am working with XYZ Ltd.

**I** have an experience of 5 years.

**I** have been working on Java platform since 5 years.

---

An XSLT 1.0 solution is also possible and is a little bit more complicated.

**Explanation**: Use of the standard XPath 2.0 function **[`tokenize()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-tokenize)** and of the standard XPath functions **[`normalize-space()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-normalize-space)** and **[`substring-after()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-substring-after)**.

Comment: @John: XPath 2.0 (only by itself) cannot create new nodes, like `<b>` in your case. What you need is an XSLT 2.0 processor (I am using in my free time a number of them and Saxon and XQSharp are quite good).

Answer (score 0):

Try using Pseudo-Element property in css

```
p:first-letter
{
font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: As per my knowledge, these pseudo elements don't have first-word element :(. And I need first word and NOT the letter...Please check the requirement above. Its <b>My</b> NOT <b>M</b>y ..

Answer (score 0):

i would work with the substring methods ..,
something like this

```
<xsl:template match="info" mode="parapgrah">
  <b><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(text(), ' ')" /></b><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(text(), ' ')" />
</xsl:template>
```

ups - this will only replace the first occurence .. you'll need to add a foreach for every 'paragraph'